# Better way to write this regular expression

Tags: java, regex

It's my first time using regular expressions and I'm sure Im missing something.
I'm trying to parse these strings in Java:

- {title} S{number} E{number}
- {title} S{number}E{number}
- {title} Season {number} Episode {number}

This is how im currently doing it:

```
String str = "How I Met Your Mother S01 E01";
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(?i)([s])(\\d*+)");
Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(str);

while (matcher1.find()) {
   System.out.println("Season: " + Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2)));
}
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("(?i)([e])(\\d*+)");
Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(str);

while (matcher2.find()) {
   System.out.println("Episode: " + Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2)));
}
```

Doing it this way, getting the title gets complicated because I basically have to remove from the string the matched strings I found before.

Im sure there's a better way so before I continue I just wanted to check.

Also, in this way, it doesn't work if the title includes the letter "s" or "e" (in the code above, for example, it would give me an error).

Comment: `(.*)\sS(?:eason\s?)?0*(\d+)\s?E(?:pisode\s?)?0*(\d+)` should capture the title in the first group, the season number in the second group, and the episode number in the third group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match all variations of S E  Season and Episode you could make the longer parts optional and match 0+ or 1+ horizontal whitespace chars in between

```
(?i)^.*\h+S(?:eason)?(\d+)\h*E(?:pisode)?\h*(\d+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EalTYS/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/zqh5CJ)

In Java with doubled escapes

```
String regex = "(?i)^.*\\h+S(?:eason)?(\\d+)\\h*E(?:pisode)?\\h*(\\d+)$";
```

Comment: Yes thanks! I knew it could be done in a single regular expression

Answer (score 0):

```java
/**
* content format
* {title} S{number} E{number}
* {title} S{number}E{number}
* {title} Season {number} Episode {number}
**/
String str = "How I Met Your Mother S01 E01";
String regex = "(?i)(.*?) (s(?:(eason )?)(?<season>\\d+)) ?(e(?:(pisode )?)(?<episode>\\d+))";
System.out.println("regex matches: " + str.matches(regex));
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group("season");
System.out.println(matcher.group("episode");
```